# What hash rate should I expect using a BiFury with USB2.0 rather than USB3.0?

Tags: asic, mining-hardware, hashpower

I'm considering the [BiFury](http://www.shortingbitcoins.com/product/bi-fury-5-ghs-usb-3-0-asic-bitcoin-miner-bifury-usa-stock/) which is generates ~5GH/s on a USB3 port. They say,

> Miner is designed to be used with USB 3.0 port or USB 3.0 hub (must meet min. 0.9A per port to achieve full hashrate)
>   USB 2.0 support is also available but hashrate will be lower.

However they don't quote an expected hash rate for USB2.0. Will it be significantly lower?

Comment: Why the down vote, this is a sensible question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that some USB2 hubs with enough amps (3-4) can take 3 BiFury each easily reaching 5.2-5.6 GH/s. I have 5 running off two 5V 3A hubs daisy chained off of a RaspberryPi with `minepeon`, works well. You 100% need a couple of fans to keep these cool, I am using arctic breeze, works fine. Errors are at about 4% and temps range from 38 to 50°.

So, the conclusion is… USB2 will work well with BiFury just make sure you have a good amount of amps to supply the thirsty 0.9A they need each! I think they are a good miner for people to get started without spending to much.